# RegEx | Match string not starting with a specific word

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, regex-negation

I am writing some mod_rewrite regex, and I have several request URLs that lookg like that

```
use1mycompany
use2mycompany
use3mycompany
use4mycompany
```

but also I have and some request URIs that start with

```
mycompany/user1mycompany/
mycompany/user2mycompany/
mycompany/user3mycompany/
mycompany/user4mycompany/
```

In order to fix that Issue I have used the following regex in apachec mod_rewrite

```
^(.*)mycompany/?$
```

the problem is that my regex matcing both the userXmycomany URL and the mycopmany/userXmycompany/

So, the question is, how can I match the urls that not starts with the string "mycompany" but end with the string "mycompany" ?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you post sample of full URLs you want to match and full URLs that you don't want to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<!mycompany)/.*(?<=mycompany)/?
```

will match /user1mycompany/ but not mycompany//user1mycompany/

Answer (score 1):

You should match string which have at least one character before `mycompany`.

`*` means 0 or more. `+` means 1 or more.

```
^(.+)mycompany/?$
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce. I know what is the meaning of asterisk and plus symbols. Althow have try your suggestion, the problem stil exists

Comment: (?<!mycompany)/.*(?<=mycompany)/?--try this